# Best rails plugin for comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, comments, rubygems

What is the best plugin or gem for adding comments to the ActiveRecord models in rails?

Maybe there is one with ability to rate each comments with votes +1/-1 (like on youtube for example) and a cool view helper to display comments in a tree?